# MemoryManagement for ObservableCollections in .Net

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, observablecollection

I am working on a WPF application in which I am working with an ObservableCollection of CustomObject

```
public ObservableCollection<ProjectsToShow> Projects{get;set;}
```

Definition for ProjectsToShow class

```
public class ProjectsToShow 
{
    public ProjectsToShow()
    {
        Wells = new ObservableCollection<WellsToShow>();
    }

    public Project ProjectObject { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<WellsToShow> _wells;

    public ObservableCollection<WellsToShow> Wells{get;set;}
}
```

This class initialize a collection for WellsToShow whose definition is

```
 public class WellsToShow 
{
    public WellsToShow()
    {
        Datasets = new ObservableCollection<DatasetsToShow>();
    }

    public Well WellObject { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<DatasetsToShow> _datasets;
    public ObservableCollection<DatasetsToShow> Datasets
    {
        get { return _datasets; }
        set
        {
            _datasets = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Datasets");
        }
    }
}
```

and one more level like this.

Now I am profiling my application using memory profiler and it keeps adding the objects in the collection to the memory. I was expecting that calling

```
Projects.Clear();
```

will release all the objects from the memory but it does not work that way. Even I try to set the Projects to null but even that did not work. Objects of WellsToShow and DatasetToShow still hold on to memory. So for testing purpose I try this code

```
foreach(var project in MainViewModel.Projects)
        {
            foreach(var well in project.Wells)
            {
                well.Datasets.Clear();                    
            }
            project.Wells.Clear();
        }
        MainViewModel.Projects.Clear();
```

As per memory profiler they are not in the memory anymore. For the record, each time I run the profiler it runs GC.Collect first and then do the profiling.

Can some please explain how this thing works. If this is the correct way to clear the collection then I need to run and fix this thing in all the projects.

Update 1, Binding this collection to view

I am binding my Project property to TreeView control and upon investigating it profiler. This control is keeping hold of my collection, I believed clearing the items source collection should do the job but this is not the case here.

```
  <TreeView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
           <TreeView.Resources>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type bll:ProjectsToShow}" ItemsSource="{Binding Wells}">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ProjectName}" x:Name="TextBlockProject" Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  >
                                                <MenuItem 
                                                          Command="{Binding FileEditProjectCommand}">
                                                    <MenuItem.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource EditProject}"/>
                                                    </MenuItem.Header>
                                                </MenuItem>

                                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding FileDeleteProjectCommand}">
                                                    <MenuItem.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource DeleteProject}"/>
                                                    </MenuItem.Header>
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type bll:WellsToShow}" ItemsSource="{Binding Datasets}">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding WellName}" Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding FileEditWellCommand}">
                                                    <MenuItem.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource EditWell}"/>
                                                    </MenuItem.Header>
                                                </MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem  Command="{Binding FileDeleteWellCommand}">
                                                    <MenuItem.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource DeleteWell}"></TextBlock>
                                                    </MenuItem.Header>
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Update 2 Screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: If you are using a profiler, check what objects are causing the wells and datasets to be rooted. It may be a view that is bound to your view models keeping them alive.

Comment: Can you please show you bindings in View?

Comment: @mikez I have updated the question. Please look into that now.

Comment: @MegaMind - Profiler also tells you details of rooted object. See what object is holding onto your references.

Comment: @RohitVats MainWindow->TreeView->System.Windows.DataBinding->DatasetsToShow

Comment: So what makes you think there is a problem here?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just want to know if we need to recursively clear the collections to free the memory instead of clearing just the parent collection.

Comment: Depends on what you want, but I would focus on why you would want this. In this case, the DatasetsToShow are bound independently of Projects. All seems OK, so unless you're seeing OOM exceptions: do nothing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That is why I am concerned with this issue, this collection has lots of data in it. Everytime I open this screen, it consumes around 30MB of memory but upon closing, only 3 or 4MB recovers. So opening the screen say 10 to 20 times or more might blow the system away.

Comment: Try opening and closing it 30 times and measure/analyze again.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have tried to do as you ask. But even the profiler runs out of juice after 10 runs. I am attaching screenshot of complete analysis with my question for better understanding.

Comment: I don't know what "runs out of juice" means but I see almost flat lines approaching maybe 300MB. Unless you're on a Phone or Tablet that doesn't indicate a problem.

Comment: I'm pressing this issue because a lot of "OMG it's using memory"
 questions posted here turn out to be imaginary problems. The burden is on you to prove a real leak/problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the visual objects corresponding to the object that are (were) in the collection, those visual objects will hold onto those references within their respective DataContexts. Make sure to run the memory profile only AFTER the objects have *visually* cleared.

I also recommend [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for any WPF debugging work, as this may be able to show your objects and what's referencing them.